# Redirecting custom taxonomies in Wordpress through Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a custom query with regex so I can redirect this:

http://www.mysite.com/category/2010/11/title-of-post/?tags=titleoftag

to this:

http://www.mysite.com/category/?tags=titleoftag

I've tried redirecting like this:

Source url: `http://www.mysite.com/category/(.*)/?tags=(.*)`

Target URL: `http://www.mysite.com/category/?tags=$2`

But this also matches the target URL in itself, so the redirection gets stuck in a loop.

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked here for me: (the delimiter of the regex is #, but you could easily change it)

```
$subject = 'http://www.mysite.com/category/2010/11/title-of-post/?tags=titleoftag';
$subject2 = 'http://www.mysite.com/category/?tags=titleoftag';

$regex = '#http://www.mysite.com/category/(.*)/\?tags=(.*)#i';

$replace = 'http://www.mysite.com/category/?tags=$2';

var_dump(preg_replace($regex, $replace, $subject)); // replaces the text correctly


$result = preg_match($regex, $subject2);
var_dump($result); // finds 0 results
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved it thanks to your answer, but I had to modify it since I had to use it in a Redirection plugin and not directly in PHP.

I did it like this:
Source URL: `/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/\?tags=(.*)`
Target URL: `/category/?tags=$4`
HTTP Code: 301 Permanently